# Surveys Screen interaction bug in the header

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, survey

In this page https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/

in the header mouse events are overtaken by the text and ruins the experience and cool effect in the background.

my suggestion is to add `pointer-events: none;` in `.hero div` selector in css.

Comment: Good suggestion. I just tested this (on Firefox), and a side-effect of `pointer-effects: none` is that the text becomes non-selectable. (Or at least, not selectable on its own - if you select from before to after it, it is included in the selection.)

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed.

I removed the `div` with the text from being nested within the hero `div`, and cleaned up the CSS using [Stacks](https://stackoverflow.design), our structured design system.